# Using a segue and an IBAction into one button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is there any way to assign a segue as well as an IBAction to a button? Also would there be a different method of attempting this of transitioning from an MPMediaPickerController (e.i, the user would be on one view controller, choose a song, and appear in another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing that would be to place the segue into the `IBAction`. That way it will run both. To keep your code clean you could create a separate method for the segue and then call that method from inside the `IBAction`.

**Example**

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
  segue()
  //do stuff
}

func segue() {
  //run the transition
}
```

Hope that helps :)